# 3 Prong navigater stays put no matter what object selected

Tags: modeling, interface

Why is my navigation xyz thing staying put no matter what object is selected? No matter what I select to move the object that thing stays where it’s at. I tried setting origin and it does nothing. I tried clicking the 3 prong icon and then it disappears totally on the modeling window. This has happened a few times now and my only way to make it work right again is I copy everything and paste it into a new document. The blend file is here:

[image]

. Thanks. [image]

Comment: agreed with comment above, seems like you set your navigation mode to 3D cursor.

Comment: Doh! I knew it was something simple. Thanks Ray and Mav. Delete the question if you wish.